# Awesomium 1.7.5 load local asset CSS file

Tags: css, awesomium

I can load local asset javascript files using this method, but I can't get it to actually bring in the CSS file. The JS file works fine this way.

Is there another way to do this without a resource interceptor, just using the built in embedded resource datasource as asset://  on an element?

I execute some javascript that appends an element into a page with:

```
    var customjs= document.createElement('script');
    customjs.type = 'text/javascript';
    customjs.src = "asset://local/Scripts/mycustom.js";
```

But when i try something similar with :

```
    var customCss = document.createElement('link');        
    customCss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    customCss.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    customCss.setAttribute("href", "asset://local/CSS/mycustom.css");
```

and appending this into the page, it does not work.

Both files are build types of embedded resource.